# Adobe air open ipad Photo and load image to the movieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Is there a way to have the file reference work under ipad?

The file reference works for flash and andriod tablet, but not the ipad.

```
/**
        * uploadNewBackground
        *
        * Sets up the position for the panel container and add Event Listener to 
        * all the buttons for different categories and also container a listener
        * for the zoom in and out function
        */      
        private function uploadNewBackground(e:MouseEvent):void{
            var imageFileTypes:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Images (*.jpg, *.png)", "*.jpg;*.png"); 

            _file = new FileReference();
            _file.browse([imageFileTypes]);
            _file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectFile);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the CameraRoll API

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/CameraRoll.html

This is a great example of how to use it

http://www.flashandmath.com/mobile/cameraroll/

Comment: I just find out some information regarding that, thanks very very much and i will give it a shoot see if it works or not! again appreciate your help. hope our air community will grow as well :)

Comment: shameless plug. If you're an IRC user there is a large and active actionscript and flex community on efnet. irc.netnet.org #actionscript